# Best way to clear a value from a ThreadLocal<T>

Tags: c#, .net

I am using a `ThreadLocal<T>` to store an item-per-thread, but every soft often, I wish to clear a thread's stored value.  How is the best way of doing this?  I can reset the instance's value to null, but the IsValueCreated property still shows true.

e.g.

```
var storage = new ThreadLocal<string>();
storage.Value = "hello";
//storage.IsValueCreated -> true
storage.Value = null;
//storage.IsValueCreated -> still true
```

Comment: That's entirely normal.  There are *two* reasons it can be null: you either never assigned the value at all or you stored null in the value.  IsValueCreated lets you tell the difference between the two.  Pretty unclear why you can't simply test for null to check for a "cleared" state.

Comment: If the actual value shouldn't ever be null, can you not just modify your current test of `storage.IsValueCreated` to be `storage.IsValueCreated&&storage.Value!=null`?

Comment: @HansPassant as it turns out, I am using null to signify 'not set', so the question is somewhat academic.  The thread is being reused, and I can think of other situations where null may be a valid result, but yeah, its easy to work around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't de-initialize the data for a single thread. There is no method to do it (other than recreating the `ThreadLocal<>`, losing all the values)

Once assigned, the value of `IsValueCreated` is `true` for that thread. `null` is a perfectly ok value, it doesn't mean "deassign the value" or "the value is not assigned".

Answer (score 0):

<s>You should dispose the instance of `ThreadLocal<string>` and remove all references to it if you are done with it and create a new one.</s>

The property `Value` is lazy initialized. So when you access the property for the first time, the value is created and the property `IsValueCreated` is set to true.

Comment: If he `Dispose()` the `ThreadLocal` he will kill all the values for all the threads. It is quite "throw a bomb to kill an ant"

Answer (score 0):

"...the IsValueCreated property still shows true." - it is.
You are set "Value = null" for current thread, but thread is still alive.